# Format date with Elixir DateTime to RFC2616 format

Tags: datetime, elixir, datetime-format, rfc2616

I want to implement a piece of code that converts a datetime object like `~U[2022-06-07 18:37:16.842920Z]` to a format like `Tue, 7 Jun 2022 18:37:16 GMT`. I do not want to use the Calendar.DateTime.Format.httpdate since our codebase already uses DateTime.

I need it to send in API headers with RFC2616 format. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note also that RFC 2616 has been deprecated in 2014. The current standard is RFC 9110, section 5.6.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elixir 1.11.0 introduced [`Calendar.strftime/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Calendar.html#strftime/3) that is what you need. Please note that `DateTime` and `Calendar` are different built-in modules that serve different purposes. There should be no problem in using them combined.

```
~U[2022-06-07 18:37:16.842920Z]
|> DateTime.shift_zone!("Etc/UTC")
|> Calendar.strftime("%a, %-d %b %Y %X GMT")
# => "Tue, 7 Jun 2022 18:37:16 GMT"
```

Comment: Any idea how to use Calendar in Elixir v1.9.4? I keep getting Calendar.strftime is private or unavailable...

Comment: @give_me_ur_btcns https://hex.pm/packages/nimble_strftime